# Pass a double** in a function that takes double as input in c

Tags: c

I tried to pass the double** as a double like this :

```
double calculErreurLocale(double erreurGlobale, double entree)
{
    return entree*(1-entree)*erreurGlobale;
}

double** matrice1()
{
    double** matrice_I;
    int i;

    matrice_I=malloc(sizeof(double*)*ligne);
    for (i=0; i<ligne; i++)
    {
        matrice_I[i]=malloc(sizeof(double)*colonne);
    }

    //affiche_matriceFloat(matrice_I);
    return matrice_I;
}

int main()
{
    double **matrice = matrice1();
    matrice[0][0]=-1;
    matrice[1][0]=-1;

    calculErreurLocale(errGlobale, matrice);
 return = 0;
}
```

Obviously I get an error. I tried to cast it or something like this :

```
calculErreurLocale(errGlobale, (double) matrice);
```

Then I get "error: pointer cannot be cast to type 'double'".

Is my problem something else, maybe the design is not correct...

Comment: "calculErreurLocale" takes two double as arguments; you pass it an array of pointers of double. You should call "calculErreurLocale" in a loop in order to pass each element of your matrix one by one (an thus give a double instead of an array of pointers).  ps : coder en français, c'est mal

Comment: Your use of global variables `ligne` and `colonne` is questionable.

Comment: @Greg I see. Thank you. ps : je suis en échange en France et ici on code en français, rip.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I know, it is for a simple script. We will change it soon.

Comment: Hammering a square bold into a round nut mostly never leads to satisfying result.

Comment: "*I tried to pass the `double**` as a `double`*" why?

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense, so maybe you could explain what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: this is your problem: *"error: pointer cannot be cast to type 'double'".*  So, are you looking for the correct way to pass the array or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

As per your function definition for `calculErreurLocale` its expected that you pass an element of the 2-D array `matrice`. If you, however, want to pass the entire array into the function and then manipulate the same, I would suggest you change the function definition to `double calculErreurLocale(double erreurGlobale, double** entree)`. The code snippet is too ambiguous to understand what you want to do with the code, but explicitly typecasting your array to a double value is not the answer.

Comment: I already tried your suggestion but it turns out that "entree" is a simple number so it can't be an array of multiple numbers... I will iterate in my array and give each value one by one instead. Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 0):

`matrice` is an array of pointers whereas your function
expects a `double`. You can only pass it one element of
the matrix at a time. For the first item in the first row:

```
calculErreurLocale(errGlobale, matrice[0][0]);
```

If you want to apply the function to each element instead,
do it in a loop similar to what `matrice1()` does.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It shows a correct example of how to pass  a double from the matrix to the function. The explanation could be better though.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Well, the question is literally “is my problem something else?”

Comment: The question is more "I tried everything I know, am I stupid?" ;)

Comment: @MrRarri :) No sweat. Could you perhaps clarify whether your function should consider all elements oft the matrix or just the one?